# Display typoscript settings in the backend

Tags: backend, typoscript, typo3-10.x

In setup.typoscript are some global settings, for example:

```
settings.termsAndConditionsUrlsDE {
  linguistik = https://www.test.ch/de/agb-2.pdf
  psychologie = https://www.test.ch/de/agb-2.pdf
}
settings.termsAndConditionsUrlsEN {
  linguistik = https://www.test.ch/en/agb-2.pdf
  psychologie = https://www.test.ch/en/agb-2.pdf
}
```

The model looks like this:

```
protected $schoolAztbUrl;

public function getSchoolAztbUrl() {
  if ($this->schoolAztbUrl === null)
    {
      $objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');
      $configurationManager = $objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Configuration\\ConfigurationManagerInterface');
      $setting = $configurationManager->getConfiguration(
        ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_SETTINGS, 'ZhawContinuingEducation', 'Course'
      );

      $context = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Context\Context::class);
      $currentLanguageUid = $context->getPropertyFromAspect('language', 'id');

      if ($currentLanguageUid == 1) {
        // set for English
        $this->setSchoolAztbUrl($setting['termsAndConditionsUrlsEN'][$this->getSchool()]);
      }else{
        // set for German (default)
        $this->setSchoolAztbUrl($setting['termsAndConditionsUrlsDE'][$this->getSchool()]);
      }
    }
    return $this->schoolAztbUrl;
}


 public function setSchoolAztbUrl($schoolAztbUrl) {
   $this->schoolAztbUrl = $schoolAztbUrl;
 }
```

So far the frontend rendering is showing the correct setting values!

The question is, how can you display the settings in the backend as readonly also? For example like this nearly:

[image]

I tried several TCA field types as none, passthrough, user. None of them worked. Is there an approach to follow?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create your own **renderType**. You can use the

```
'type'=>'user',
'renderType' => 'yourType'
```

It is pretty easy, you can actually use the same function you used to get the values in FrontEnd. Although i would write the function to a helper class which you can call on your model and on your own TCA type.

Documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/10.4/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/User.html

Best regards

Comment: Aristeidis Karavas, thanks for your response. What do you mean with helper class in TYPO3? Is there a documentation?

Comment: you can create a simple class with the name Helper under the Classes/Helper/Helper.php and write your function to get the settings in there. Then you can call the function in your Domain Model and your renderType class. This way you have the function only once and can be used anywhere by just calling it